# How to print special letter such as A and D

Tags: letters

[image]

[image]

How to print the "A" and "D" that looks like the graphs? I tried to use \textit but it does not work?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}$\mathcal{AD}$\end{document}`

Comment: You are most certainly looking for `\mathcal{A}` and `\mathcal{D}`